# Mysqli bind_param() doesnt work as expected

Tags: mysqli, bind, param

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?
When I execute and fetch this I'm becoming the correct Result.

```
$message = '100';
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select english from table where message=? LIMIT 1")) {
$stmt = bind_param("i", $message);
} //Return the Message in English
```

But when I put the language into a variable and use bind_param().
I just get the new variable as a result back ex.:

```
$message = '100';
$language = 'english';
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select ? from table where message=? LIMIT 1")) {
$stmt = bind_param("si", $language, $message);
} //Returns "english"
```

I guess the Problem is that the "$language" is binded as a "String". What would be the correct type? Tried allready to change it to blob or double with no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look what does `bind_param` do.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select * from users where name=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", "Dennis");
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select * from users where name='Dennis'");
```

<sub>However, using bind_param is much safer than inserting value by hands into SQL-query. Because when inserting value by hands, you need to carefully handle special characters; otherwise maliciously-constructed value can make SQL-parser to consider parts of the value not as value, but as commands, table names, column names, etc. The bind_param does it for you; with bind_param you don't hane to worry about that `Dennis` should be turned into `'Dennis'` before inserting into SQL-query, but `Dennis O'Brian` should turn into `'Dennis O\'Brian'` (not `'Dennis O'Brian'`), and [NUL-character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) should turn into `'\0'` (not remain as NUL-character).</sub>

The bind_param is suitable only for inserting **values** into SQL-query. Because when you need to insert **column or table name** into SQL-query, you actually need the opposite -- you need column name to be inserted into SQL-query directly (without adding any quotes, etc). So you actually need:

```
select english from table where message=... LIMIT 1
```

not

```
select 'english' from table where message=... LIMIT 1
```

So, just do it:

```
$message = '100';
$language = 'english';
$sql = "select " . $language . " from table where message=? LIMIT 1";
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $message);
}
```

The only thing is that you *must be sure than `$language` contains valid column name*. Otherwise, if user forced something bad to be passed through `$language`, you'll get [SQL-injection](http://en.wikipedia.com/SQL-injection).

```
$message = ...;
$language = ...;
...;
if(!in_array($language, array('english', 'german', 'french'), true))
    $language = 'english';
$sql = "select " . $language . " from table where message=? LIMIT 1";
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $message);
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you for the fast and detailed answer. This helped a lot